# How to create extern for jquery-ui-widget.js

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I searched the whole StackOverflow but unable to find any clues how to create extern file for jquery-ui-widget (not the complete jquery-ui).

Please help me. I am struck with only this issue to convert all my JS files to GCC compliant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want extern file for jquery-ui-widget.js or jquery-ui.js files so that I can use these with google closure compiler.

Comment: You **need** to use the tags field correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc